# IOS6 Incorrect TimeZone while converting date from string to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsdate, date-conversion

My date is in the format

2013-07-16T07:40:36.939-04:00

When I convert it into a NSDate
the date is in the format IST or GMT +5:30 as I am in India. How should I make it use -4:00 as the timezone and display EST or PDT as per the number. if I use zzz, it returns GTM+5:30 and zzzz returns Indian Standard Time. This is my way

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSzzz"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the formatted locale to `en_US_POSIX` to force it to use the supplied timezone instead of the system timezone:

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
```

Comment: didn't make any difference

Answer (score 1):

You're parsing the date string correctly (in iOS 6 and later; this is not date format recognized in iOS 5 which recognizes `-0400` or `GMT-04:00`, but not `-04:00`). Unfortunately, `NSDate` objects do not have a "time zone", so that information is not captured by the `NSDateFormatter`.

If you really want to capture the original timezone, I think you may have to manually parse the string for those last few characters (the `-04:00`), determine the timezone offset from that, and store this in a separate field and when outputting the date, use this separate time zone offset to set the `timeZone` property of your date formatter accordingly. Or if you really want to represent the original date, you could reformat this ISO8601 date string as human-friendly string and keep this pretty string (as well as the `NSDate` object, presumably).

BTW, splitting hairs, but you might want to be wary about assuming that `-04:00` will represent `EDT` because (a) it depends upon the time of the year; and (b) there are other timezones that are also `-04:00` (e.g. there are a bunch of South American timezones that are also `-04:00`).

Generally apps avoid this problem altogether by (a) converting the date strings to `NSDate` objects; and (b) output these `NSDate` objects using the timezone and locale of the device that the app is running on.

Comment: there has to be a way to work that out. i dont want implement the hack where i have the hard coded values for timezones and i compare the data ... that would be the last solution... and then also i might not want to go there...

Comment: -4:00 represents the server time... and requirement is as such i have to display that timezone...

Comment: @PeyushGoel Understood. If you want to always display dates in the `-4:00` timezone, that's easy (just use that timezone in your output `NSDateFormatter`). But I thought that some dates were going to be in a `-4:00` timezone and others where going to be in, for example, a `-7:00` timezone and you wanted to display them in the timezone of the original date string (e.g. `EDT` v `PDT`) on the basis of the timezone captured in that original string. Unfortunately, `NSDate` simply doesn't capture the timezone, so if you need to save the timezone, you'll need to do that manually.

Comment: usually it would be just 1 format but it could be multiple. but I would get the value from the server that its -4:00 or -7:00. That part is clear. What is not clear is how should I use it with NSDateFormatter. The above approach (in my question) returns date in my system time i.e. IST

Comment: @PeyushGoel Not to split hairs, but it's not returning a `NSDate` in your system time (because `NSDate` doesn't understand timezones). It's just returning the date without a timezone. But when you examine the contents of the `NSDate`, it will, by default, show it to you in your system's default timezone. If you want, though, you can manually set the `timeZone` property of the `NSDateFormatter`, e.g. `dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:-4.0 * 60.0 * 60.0];` and then look at `[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]`, and it should show it to you in `GMT-4:00` format.

Comment: @PeyushGoel You can also use timezone names, e.g. if you wanted PDT, you could use `dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Los_Angeles"];` If you wanted EDT, you could use `dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"];`